# How to solve $F=-\vec{\nabla}\phi$?

Tags: calculus

Where $F$ is the equation of a force and $\phi$ is a distance function with 
$$
\phi(r)=38\left[e^{-8\left(r-1.25\right)}-2e^{-4\left(r-1.25\right)}\right]+38.5
$$

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem defined in cartesian or cylindrical coordinates? Depending on this you will apply the gradient to $\phi$ in such coordinates.

Comment: The problem just sais it is a model for the energy (kcal/mol) of a system of two particles as a function of the distance... I think that the problem is not properly enunciated...

Comment: Well, since the energy only depends on the distances of two particles, I'd assumed spherical coordinates, you just need to derive with respect to r. So the force is F = 304*(e^(10 - 8*r) - e^(5 - 4*r))*e_r where e_r is the radial unit vector. 
Review the calculations.